# Android Studio ScrollView blurred content

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 and I have problem with a scrollView that I can not solve.
The issue is, that if I add a button to the scrollview, then, when I scroll the panel, the button leaves blurred trace behind. 
(like in old windows, when PC froze, moving a window on a screen would result in leaving trace on desktop, as desktop would not be redrawn)

Here is an illustration
[image: The grey square buttons were added, and at the bottom you can see like there are more buttons under it, where as, in reality, there are not, it is just not redrawn background]

The grey square buttons were added, and at the bottom you can see like there are more buttons under it, where as, in reality, there are not, it is just not redrawn background

This problem happens when doing followind by both editing xml or constructing GUI programatically

1. Adding only one or more buttons directly to scrollview
2. Adding TableLayout to ScrollView, then adding TableRow, to that I add button
3. Adding TableLayout to ScrollView, then adding TableRow, to that I add Frame layout and to that button

The virtual emulator I use is
[image: The emulator used to run code]

Please, If any of you knows where might be the issue, could you point me in right direction? Below I provide the code

The code in GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //hide status bar
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    //add components
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ID_HealthImageView);
    mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);

    //init table layout content
    createGui_FillTable((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.ID_table_layout), 6, 3, 210);
}
private void createGui_FillTable(TableLayout tl, int rows, int cols, int size_of_button)
{
    if(rows <= 0 || cols <= 0)
        return;

    for(int z = 0; z < rows; z++) {
        TableRow TR = new TableRow(this);
        TR.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            TR.addView(create_button_forTable(size_of_button));

        tl.addView(TR, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
private Button create_button_forTable(int size_of_button)
{
    //frame layout first
    /*FrameLayout FL = new FrameLayout(this);
    FL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*/

    //button
    Button B = new Button(this);
    B.setText("");
    B.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(size_of_button, size_of_button));

    //FL.addView(B);
    return B;
}
```

here, the main method to focus on is the following call

```
createGui_FillTable((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.ID_table_layout), 6, 3, 210);
```

Now the Activity_game.xml contains this code (complete cut and paste)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="janglaser.survival.GameActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/ID_HealthImageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/ID_table_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ID_HealthImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you for any kind response or advice, and also for your time if you red up to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The issue was that parent container and also the Table Layout container did not have a background color specified, thus it was not redrawing.